# How do I fake a iOS device rotation in Flash

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

I need to fake a device rotation in my app, so that in Quick Time movie mode it rotates for presentations.

I've tried several options, but the one that seems most promising is allowing autoOrient to stay true but preventing any changes to screen orientation. The issue is, I can't figure out a way to to do this. I have been using e.preventDefault() but it has had no effect. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "ACCELEROMETER" in the flash Simulator

[image]